# Interface inheritance and return data type as a subclass

Tags: java, oop

**Problem**

I'm thinking how to design an interface hierarchy in my Java app to meet my needs. I need to extend my service interface and return more detailed `dto`-s.

**Contracts**

I have this interface to define a datatype of a service:

```
public interface IEnvelopeService<T extends EnvelopeDto> {

   T findActiveEnvelope(UUID envelopeId);

// the rest is omitted for brevity   
}
```

it works as I need.

But in one usecase I need to "enrich" the datatype `EnveloptDto` by another information, so I created an enriched service implementation to return these enriched dto-s.

New interface extending previous contract to define a new datatype:

```
public interface IRichEnvelopeService extends IEnvelopeService {

}
```

and that's an example implementation:

```
public class RichEnvelopeService implements IRichEnvelopeService {
EnvelopeRichDto findActiveEnvelope(UUID envelopeId){
//....
}
}
```

**DTO**

Main, parent, DTO:

```
public class EnvelopeDto{
// ommited...    
}
```

and extended DTO:

```
public class EnvelopeRichDto extends EnvelopeDto{
// ommited...
}
```

**Question**

Is this what I proposed good way how to achieve my needs? Is there something what can be done better and what violate OOP principles in Java?

Comment: might be a typo but your interface has the exact same name as the implementation class

Comment: @Stultuske fixed, thanks